# DatabaseError: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Tags: oracle, dataframe, insert, cx-oracle

I'm a new oracle learner. I'm trying to insert a pandas dataframe into an oracle table. I have made research online, the code itself (https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/704409/Insert-pandas-dataframe-to-Oracle-databa/) should be very simple, but I don't know why my code doesn't work.

I have read the pandas dataframe from my local file:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))
df = pd.read_csv(dir_path+"/sample.csv")
```

Now print df, the dataframe df shold be like this:

```
   DATE            YEAR     MONTH      SOURCE      DESTINATION
0  11/1/2017 1:00  2017     1          AL          CO  
1  11/2/2017 1:00  2017     5          GA          ID  
2  11/3/2017 1:00  2017     12         GA          MO
```

Then I create connection with the database by using cx_Oracle. Next I try to insert the dataframe df into the table TEST. This table TEST is an empty table which already exist in oracle database, it has columns including DATE, YEAR, MONTH, SOURCE, DESTINATION in oracle. All the datatype matches the data of df. My code is as follows:

```
conn_str = u'account/password@host:1521/server'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Write records stored in a DataFrame to a oracle database
rows = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
print(rows)
cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO TEST (DATE,YEAR,MONTH,SOURCE,DESTINATION) 
                   VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)''',rows)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

It shows error:

> DatabaseError: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

How to solve the problem? Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATE` is a reserved word in Oracle SQL. You need to quote it (or rename your column to something that isn't a reserved word). `YEAR` is a reserved word too, needs the same treatment.

```
insert into test("DATE", ...
```

When quoted like this, the case must match that used in the table definition.

Full list of reserved words and keywords: [Oracle (12c) SQL Reserved Words and Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd.htm#SQLRF022)